# add ComboBox dynamically with Locations in UWP

Tags: c#, combobox, uwp

I am new in this technology. Problem is I am not able to add location dynamically to ComboBox. I have a Button which add a comboBox on click event. Button should add ComboBox below the first one. I have write this code:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox combobox = new ComboBox();
        combobox.ItemsSource = credithr_list;
        // Location of comboBox should add here
        grid2.Children.Add(combobox);
    }
```

how should I modify it, so I can achieve my desired result.

Comment: what is your desired result exactly? care to explain more about what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: I need to add combo box dynamically every time I click add button. and new ComboBox will appear below to the previous ComboBox.
And sorry I have not good English.

Comment: @AlphaBot It seems that you use Grid as a container. If I understand you right, try to replace grid with StackPanel. Because now each Click adds a combobox but all of them are drawn on the same place.

Comment: The problem with your original code is that you're adding the combobox to a grid. By default all children are added at cell 0,0 in the grid. There are many options to fix this depending on your requirements. You could put Grid.Row property on the combobox and set it to 1, use a RelativePanel instead of a grid, or use a StackPanel instead of a grid.

Comment: I have used StackPanel and it fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is based on the `RelativePanel` control in UWP XAML.

Your comboboxes will live inside the relative panel and using its attached properties such as: Below, Above, etc... you can get the result you want.

Here is what I did:

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //create the combo box
        var comboBox = new ComboBox();
        //add the items to it
        comboBox.Items.Add("1");
        comboBox.Items.Add("2");

        //if there are no items in the relative panel, then the first combo box should go at the top
        if (RelPanel.Children.Count == 0)
        {
            RelPanel.Children.Add(comboBox);
            RelativePanel.SetAlignTopWithPanel(comboBox, true);
        }
        else
        {
            //if there are items already, the new combo box goes below the last one added
            RelativePanel.SetBelow(comboBox, RelPanel.Children.Last());
            RelPanel.Children.Add(comboBox);
        }
    }
```

hopefully this helps you and is what you wanted.

Edit: you can use a stackpanel but the relative panel gives you more control over placement of items.

Answer (score 0):

You can add combobox in this way:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox combobox = new ComboBox();
        combobox.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string item in new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" })
        {
            combobox.Items.Add(item);
        }
        this.Controls.Add(combobox);
    }
```

Comment: I know how to add items in combo box. I need to add combo box dynamically every time I click add button